# Powershell HTML email formatting

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, html-email

The below script puts database backup details into a nicely formatted table with borders and saves as a .htm. It then emails the report, but when the report is emailed the 'table' has no borders and no gap between the 'LastBackupDate' column and the 'LastLogBackupDate' column - it basically looks the same as the results would on the powershell console. Can anyone tell me how to format the email so all the html is used from the file? P.s. I can't use send-mailmessage due to issues with gmail ssl. Thanks.

```
#HTML 
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

#Set Date
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyyMMdd')

#Locate DB
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
$s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "LOCALHOST\SQLX64"

#Retrieves the last backup dates - for full and log backups
$dbs=$s.Databases
$backups = $dbs | SELECT Name,LastBackupDate, LastLogBackupDate | Sort-Object LastBackupDate | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>DB01 Database Backup Details $date </H2>" | Out-File $("D:\SQL_Backup_Log_Script\Logs\Backup_Log_Temp.htm")

#Email Report
$EmailFrom = "someone@domain.com"
$emailto = "me@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Database Backup Log $date" 
$Body = Get-Content D:\SQL_Backup_Log_Script\Logs\Backup_Log_Temp.htm
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("someone@domain.com", "password here"); 
$message = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
$message.IsBodyHtml = $true;
$SMTPClient.Send($message)

#Rename file to include today's date
Rename-Item -path D:\SQL_Backup_Log_Script\Logs\Backup_Log_Temp.htm -newname ($date +"_DB01_Backup_Log.htm")
```

Comment: As an aside, consider replacing your "$a = $a + " repetition with 'here strings' in PowerShell. It'll make your life a little easier. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx

Comment: +1 @xcud. Charlotte, the file looks OK in your browser before you send it out?

Comment: Shay, yes the .htm file is looking good.

Comment: @xcud - thanks, yes that is useful and will make life easier.

Comment: Adapted to my databes it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this line (can't test if is this the problem):

```
$Body = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("D:\SQL_Backup_Log_Script\Logs\Backup_Log_Temp.htm")
```

the `body` property in `Net.Mail.MailMessage` accept `[string]`, get-content return `[string[]]`.

Comment: Thanks but the emailed report hasn't changed.

Comment: Just realised, the email has been formatting fine the whole time, just GMAIL won't display the formatting. It looks good in Outlook!